# IS there a way to access data-binding in span tag and store it in a variable in the script tag? knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js

[oi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOeX4.png)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm small" >
<thead class="bg-dark text-light">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Id</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Nationality</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-right"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle" data-bind="text:DriverId"></td>
        <td class="align-middle" data-bind="text:Name"></td>
        <td class="align-middle">  
            <span id = "nation" data-bind="text:Nationality" class="float-left"> </span>
            
            <img  id="flagicon" src="" alt="" class="flag float-right float-center" />
            <script>
                
                
                var alpha_2_code = "pt";
                
               /* for(let i=0; i < countrycodesobj.length ; i++){
                    if(countrycodes[i].Nationality === (data-bind = "text:Nationality"))
                        alpha_2_code = countrycodes[i].alpha_2_code;
                }*/
                
                var myPath = "https://countryflagsapi.com/png/" + alpha_2_code;
                document.getElementById("flagicon").src= myPath;
            </script>

        </td>
       
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want the information > data-bind="text:Nationality"  < stored in a variable in script tag.
Im getting the information from an api and its being handled by knockoutjs. My knockoutjs knowledge is scarce and i dont know if i can access the information  data-bind="text:Nationality" in the script tags. Any solution whether in jquery , knockouts or javascript would be perfect.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code as a codeblock or runnable snippet & not as a screenshot.

Comment: Independently of the screenshot, you *already have* the value of `Nationality` in your script. Take your viewmodel and read the observable named `Nationality`.

Comment: @tomalak with getelementbyid.val()? is that what you mean?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You *are* writing this application, aren't you? Who did the knockout part?

Comment: @Tomalak not me a professor.

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of a simple function that you define before you applyBindings with knockout and after your countrycodesobj is defined, sth like:

```
function getFlagByNationality(n) {
    var alpha_2_code = "pt";
                
    for(let i=0; i < countrycodesobj.length ; i++){
      if(countrycodes[i].Nationality == n ){
         alpha_2_code = countrycodes[i].alpha_2_code;
      }
    }
    return "https://countryflagsapi.com/png/"+alpha_2_code;
}
```

you can then use this in data-bind attribute:

```
<img src="" data-bind="attr:{src: getFlagByNationality(Nationality)}"  />
```